# Calling and executing vb script by opening command prompt through Batch file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am a complete amateur when it comes to vb scripting or even command line so please bear with me..

I have created a vb script **send.vbs** for Sending Keys using Wshshell.sendkeys. In this script, i am going into vshell using vsh command, i get two options after i enter vsh, out of which i select option 2, and then i am executing a command whose output is redirected to a text file. i then ftp this file to a diferent server. Now i want to schedule this vb script to run every 10 min. Now, if i double click this script file, it just opens a black window for a moment and shuts it down. The commands are not executed. But when i open a command window manually and then i go to the path where the script is and then i execute it, it works fine and i get the desired output.

I tried writing a batch file with **cscript send.vbs** and scheduling the same to run every 10 min. but this batch file does not run the vbscript. Can any1 help me to write a batch fiel which will open a command prompt and then run thi vb script in that command prompt. The script is as follows:

```
Set WshShell = wscript.CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
wshshell.sendkeys "vsh"
wshshell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
wshshell.sendkeys "2"
wshshell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
wshshell.sendkeys "tls display agents > Agentstat.txt"
wshshell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
wshshell.sendkeys "quit"
wshshell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
```

Any help is highly appreciated.. 
Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go ...

```
Set WshShell = wscript.CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd"
WScript.Sleep 100 
WshShell.AppActivate "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" 
WScript.Sleep 100 
wshshell.sendkeys "vsh"
wshshell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
wshshell.sendkeys "2"
wshshell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
wshshell.sendkeys "tls display agents > Agentstat.txt"
wshshell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
wshshell.sendkeys "PAUSE"
wshshell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
wshshell.sendkeys "quit"
wshshell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
```

Comment: Hi Mootieman.. i tried the same but still the same thing. the window opens momentarily and shuts down.. even if i enter pause. if i manually open a command window and enter this command, i am getting the output. but if i double click on the batch file itself, it doesnt run. i tried placing the batch file where the send.vbs is present as well as other locations. but no use... do i need to put any kind of wait or sleep in the batch file so that it allows some time for the vbscript to run????

Comment: I would double check every step. If you add the "pause" command to the bottom of the batch file, save it, and double click it. Then the window will stay open. - Another thing you can try is to run the batch file from the command prompt (same as what you are running the script successfully)

Comment: HI.. pause command does make the window stay open but its not giving me any kind of error. It just says "Press any key to continue..". Also, if i run the batch file through command prompt, it does NOT work. When i enter the command, only then i do get the output..

Comment: Basically what i get is the vbscript needs an open command line window where it can run the script. So is there any way where i can open a command line window through some command and then execute this script in that window. If you can suggest any changes in the VB script to achieve the same, thats also fine wid me..

Comment: I duplicated what you were doing, and I got the same errors (or lack of errors) as you. This code section will probably be an easier solution.

Comment: Hi Mootieman... thanks a ton mate... the revised script is working now :)